# Error using Rasterizer Scissoring in xna

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to use Scissoring to clip a text that is drawn using the spriteBatch.DrawString method.

The following is part of my Draw method:

```
    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {

    ...

        spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = new RasterizerState();
        spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState.ScissorTestEnable = true;

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
        rectangle.Height = 50;
        rectangle.Width = 1;  //set to 1 just so I'll immediately know if it's working

        spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.ScissorRectangle = rectangle;

        for (int i = 0; i < career.news.Count; i++)
        {
            Vector2 newsItems = new Vector2(200 + i * 80, 550);
            spriteBatch.DrawString(DefaultText, career.news[i], newsItems, Color.Black);
        }

        spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState.ScissorTestEnable = false;

  ...

  }
```

I get the following error:

"Cannot change read-only RasterizerState. State objects become read-only the first time they are bound to a GraphicsDevice. To change property values, create a new RasterizerState instance."

Which I don't really understand because I've created a new instance in the above code. What am I missing?

EDIT: Amended code - errors removed but clipping still not working:

```
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
        rectangle.Height = 50;
        rectangle.Width = 1;

        RasterizerState rasterizerState = new RasterizerState();
        rasterizerState.ScissorTestEnable = true;
        spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = rasterizerState;

        spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.ScissorRectangle = rectangle;

        for (int i = 0; i < career.news.Count; i++)
        {
            Vector2 newsItems = new Vector2(200 + i * 80, 550);
            spriteBatch.DrawString(DefaultText, career.news[i], newsItems, Color.Black);
        }

        RasterizerState rasterizerState2 = new RasterizerState();
        rasterizerState2.ScissorTestEnable = false;
        spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = rasterizerState2;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What this means is you can't modify the `spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState` property. What you need to do is create an instance, set its properties, and then pass it to the `spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState`.

```
RasterizerState r = new RasterizerState();
r.ScissorTestEnable  = true;
spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = r;
....
RasterizerState r1 = new RasterizerState();
r1.ScissorTestEnable = false;
spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = r1;
```

Comment: Thank you for such a prompt response. That makes perfect sense now! I've edited the code to reflect those changes - but the clipping doesn't seem to be working? I set the width to 1 so was expecting for nearly all the text to not show, yet each "newsItem" shows up exactly as before.

Answer (score 2):

Managed to sort this out myself.

It turns out the the scissoring is only done at spriteBatch.End().

Therefore I need to End all drawing up to this point, use the below spriteBatch.Begin() overload, spriteBatch.End() to end the clipped drawing, and restart the rest of the drawing with spriteBatch.Begin(..)

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend, null, null, rasterizerState);
```

Comment: Glad you figured out the second part. :) I was working on trying to duplicate what you were doing, but you figured it out before I could. +1